# Unity C# loops: Health Bar with Hearts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem, I would like to add a halfHeart image to empty bar if the currentHealth is 25 or its multiple except of multiples of 50, because if currentHealth is for example 50 I want to show my fullHeart image in the bar where the halfHeart image used to be. I used the if I < currentHealt / 50 which shows fullHeart image inside of the empty bar if the players hp is 50, 100, 150, 200 etc. Now I just want to use the halfHearts if there are 2 fullHeart so the current hp is for example 100 and we drink potion which adds 25, so the currentHealt will be 125 which means we want a halfHeart to take place.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 600;
    public int currentHealth;
    public int numOfHearts;
    public Transform attackPoint;
    public LayerMask enemyLayers;

    public float attackRange = 0.5f;
    public int attackDamage = 50;

    public float attackRate = 2f;
    float nextAttackTime = 0f;

    public Image[] hearts;
    public Sprite fullHeart;
    public Sprite halfHeart;
    public Sprite emptyHeart;



    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Time.time >= nextAttackTime)
        {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                Attack();
                nextAttackTime = Time.time + 1f / attackRate;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
        {

            if (i < currentHealth / 50)
            {

                hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;

                if (currentHealth % 50 == 0 - 25)
                {

                }


            }
            else
            {

                hearts[i].sprite = emptyHeart;

            }

            if (i < numOfHearts)
            {
                hearts[i].enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                hearts[i].enabled = false;
            }

        }

    }

    void Attack()
    {
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);
        }

    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        if (attackPoint == null)
            return;

        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackPoint.position, attackRange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Image.type` to `Filled` and then set the `fillMethod` to `Horizontal`. Set the anchor to the left side for left to right fill.  Then specify how much of the image is filled using the `Image.fillAmount` from code.

This allows for fractional amounts of the hearts to be shown.

`fillAmount` is a float from 0 to 1, 0 being nothing filled, 1 being fully filled.  [Here is an example provided by Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html)

An example in the context of your code could be something like..

```
var remainingHeartsHealth = myCurrentHealth;

foreach (var heartImage in heartImages)
{
    // Get the health value for this heart, max of 50
    //
    var thisHeartsHealth = Mathf.Min(remainingHeartsHealth, 50);

    // Normalize the hearts health to be between 0 and 1
    //
    heartImage.fillAmount = thisHeartsHealth / 50f;

    // Update the remaining health to be used for hearts, 
    // subtracting the amount we just used, but making sure to not go below 0
    //
    remainingHeartsHealth = Mathf.Max(remainingHeartsHealth - thisHeartsHealth, 0);
}
```